# App manifest resources test - Failed Branding validation

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

While deploying windows phone application to app store, at the stage of Windows App Certification Kit evaluation the test gets failed, and details are as below,

The branding validation test encountered the following errors.
The images used are default one.

I have changed the names of images then also, the same error regarding default images is reproduced.

Comment: Try changing them by editing the `Visual Assets` part of the Package.appxmanifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we create new project, the default images are used and a encrypted code by binary data of image is generated. Even we change the name of image then also binary data in image is still same. So not only rename the image but also edit the contains.

Answer (score 1):

After Replacing Default images, you need to Build Project in Release Configuration.
App Cerification Kit run test only on these compiled binary.